# Using Express.js and NodeJS, Can you send JSON via redirect in the response body

Tags: json, node.js, express

I am trying to send JSON via a 302 redirect.  Is that possible in ExpressJS.  The API states that a body can be added the `res.json()`.  For example:

```
res.json(302, {'name': 'larry'}).
```

On the receiving end (where the redirect goes too) the body is empty. Here is some sample code:

**Sending App**

```
app.get('/hello', function(req,res){
  var data = {'name': 'larry'};
  res.set('location', 'http://www.example.com/sending');
  res.json(302, data);
});
```

**Receiving App**

```
app.get('/sending', function(req,res){
  console.log('Body: ' + req.body)
  res.send(req.body);
});
```

Note: the response headers for the 302 show a correct content-length of the data, but the receiving end shows an empty object.

Comment: Redirecting is meant for redirections, you should not send data with it (unless textual representations of the redirect, usually omitted by user agents).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your code doesn't make sense.  In the first route, you tell Express to respond with a 302 redirect and send some data.  **It is sending your JSON** to the client, something you can see in the fact that you're getting a correct `Content-Length`.

However, your second route can't work.  Firstly, `GET` requests **cannot** have a body; `req.body` will *always* be empty.

Secondly, it looks like you're assuming a client receiving a redirect will resubmit the entity-body of the redirect response in its request to the target (*example.com/sending* in this case).  This is incorrect.

- A spec-compliant HTTP client will never send a server's *response* as the body of another *request*.
- HTTP clients traditionally treat a 302 like a 303, meaning that the request to the target URL is always a `GET` request, even if the original request was a `POST`.  Thus, it is impossible for the redirected request to contain any kind of body.

If you want to send some kind of data to another server, you have two options:

- Send the data on the query string with a 303 redirect.

  ```
  // I'll use the built-in querystring module to convert an object into
  // a properly URL-encoded query string.
  res.redirect(303, '/url?' + querystring.stringify(data));
  ```
- Respond 200 and use browser-side trickery to `POST` the data to the real destination.

  ```
  res.send('<form id="redir" method="post" action="/url">' +
           '<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar">' +
           // ...
           '</form>' +
           '<script>document.getElementById("redir").submit()</script>');
  ```

  Ugly, but works ***if*** this is intended for browsers.  It won't work with requests made by servers or other non-browser tools.  You might also want to include a "Continue" submit button for the luddites that insist on browsing with JS disabled.

  I would only use this method if the amount of data you have will make the query string exceed the amount of characters practically allowable in a URL (~[2048](https://stackoverflow.com/q/812925/201952)) or if the data payload contains sensitive content, which should generally not be included in the query string.

Comment: Doesn't a 307 redirect preserve the POST method and its original data?

Comment: Yes, *request* data.  HTTP clients will never POST *response* data received in a redirect response.